# Why do I get "Multiple markers at this line: Groovy expecting EOF found 'for'"?

Tags: groovy

The Error in the Question was generated by the following code
package ian.eg.learn

```
 class ReadXMLfile {    
   def customers = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN    
                   \\Documents\\customers.xml"))
   for (customer in customers.corporate.customer){
     println "${customer.@name} works for ${customer.@company}"
   }
 }
```

I am using a regular "for" and I don't see why the compiler is having a problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of Groovy you're using so the exact error message could vary, but you cannot just write statements like that anywhere in your class, so the compiler expects something else in place of your `for` statement.

Example:

```
class Xxx {
  println("yoo")
}
```

Gives:

```
unexpected token: println @ line 2, column 3.
 println("yoo")
 ^
```

You need to move that code in a method, or an init block... anywhere but not directly in class body.

Comment: I got this code out of "Groovy in Action" page 12 (Chapter 1)

Comment: Perhaps you found that example in a Groovy book, but I'm sure that was not literally like that, not in a *class*. I found your example [here](https://github.com/demian0311/groovykata/blob/master/groovy_in_action/chapter1/chapter1.groovy), the XML-reading bit is not directly within a class. A class has same structure as in Java, with fields, methods, and init blocks (static init, instance init). But no random statements in the middle.

Comment: I found the answer, and I know that some who have given an answer didn't quite word it this way. It is what qlown said. you can't use class closures to put random code. The ide I was using didn't give me a choice of Groovy class separate from Groovy Script so the workaround here is to use the Wizard to generate the class file and get rid of the class enclosure inside the file.